# Concatenate Custom Field Value & HTML Value

Tags: php, custom-field

I have the following code, and I am attempting to concatenate the values of the echo html code & 'the_meta'. Can anyone please suggest an edit to code to get this working?

**CURRENT CODE**

```
<?php echo '<p style="text-align:left;font-size:18px;margin-bottom:5px;">
<span style="color: #000000;">By AUTHOR FOR</span> <?php the_meta(); ?>  </p>'; ?>
```

**DESIRED RESULT**

By AUTHOR FOR A GREAT MAGAZINE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display `the_meta ()` after the 'by author for' text just needs a small change:

```
<p style="text-align:left;font-size:18px;margin-bottom:5px;"><span style="color: #000000;">By AUTHOR FOR</span> <?php the_meta (); ?></p>
```

However I'm not sure you want to use `the_meta ()`, because all values get displayed, and in an unordered list. (Reference: [the_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_meta).)

Instead you probably want [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/), so:

```
<p style="text-align:left;font-size:18px;margin-bottom:5px;"><span style="color: #000000;">By AUTHOR FOR</span> <?php echo get_post_meta (get_the_ID (), 'my-author-meta-key', true); ?></p>
```

Replacing `my-author-meta-key` with your meta key name, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding echo ""; inside the tag like this:

```
 <?php the_meta(echo "somethin" ); ?>
```

Comment: I would like the value of the html echo first and then the value of 'meta_data' second. Presumably the above wouldn't achieve this?

Comment: It's all wrapped in one paragraph, I assume it will appear the order I see it, perhaps you could give it a try